# How to add a Marker into MarkerList?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to coding , feel so bad to ask this stupid question , I train Parkour for 6 years , Parkour need good spots to train , so I want to make a APP to let people take a photo and upload with spot location and information , I google for 6 hours , find out if wanna add multiple markers to the map , use `ArrayList<Marker> markerArray = new ArrayList<>();` and add markers to the map use    , and My question is , How to add marker into the makeryArray?
Please help , stuck here for 6 hours :(

I make two marker first

```
  MarkerOptions markerOpt1 = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOpt1.position(new LatLng(25.033611, 121.565000));
    markerOpt1.title("Taipei_101");
    markerOpt1.snippet("some information");
    markerOpt1.draggable(false);
    markerOpt1.visible(true);
    markerOpt1.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);

    //Marker2
    MarkerOptions markerOpt2 = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOpt2.position(new LatLng(25.047924, 121.517081));
    markerOpt2.title("TMS");
```

Put this two marker in MarkerArrayList

```
 ArrayList<Marker> markerArray = new ArrayList<>();
    markerArray.add(markerOpt1,markerOpt2); <---ERROR , it said <Int Index,Marker Object> I think markerop1 and markerop2 are Marker object already right?
```

Print Markers on map

```
 for (int i =0 ; i<markerArray.size();i++){
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerArray.get(i).getPosition())
                        .title(markerArray.get(i).getTitle())
                        .snippet(markerArray.get(i).getSnippet())
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong array append.
use

```
markerArray.add(markerOpt1);
markerArray.add(markerOpt2);
```

There are two overloads of add method:

```
@Override public boolean add(E object) {...}
```

and the second:

```
@Override public void add(int index, E object) {...}
```

So JVM and compiler think you want to usethe second overload.

Comment: Thanks , you mean two kinds of .add(), so it confuses , so how I use the right one?

Comment: @AweiHsue ,  use `markerArray.add(markerOpt1);
markerArray.add(markerOpt2);`

Comment: OH!! I got it!here: `ArrayList<Marker> markerArray = new ArrayList<>();`   should be ArrayList<MarkerOption> markerArray = new ArrayList<MarkerOption>();
 it works now , thank you !